# How do I get text near the checkboxes?

Tags: javascript

Javascript Code:

```
function loadsims(){
    var i = 1;
    $.ajax({ url: 'simulationcontent.php',
         data: {action:'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
            var a = JSON.parse(output);
            var b = a.length;
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < b;i++){
            console.log(a[i]['idi']);
            console.log(a[i]['simname']);

            if (a[i]['idi'] != 0)
            {
            for (var j=0 ;j < 1;j++)
                {
                    var cbxval = a[i]['simname'];
                    var chckbx = document.createElement("input");
                    document.getElementById('checkboxdiv').appendChild(chckbx);
                    chckbx.type = "checkbox";
                    chckbx.id = "simnamecbx"+i;
                    chckbx.name = "simnamecbx";
                    chckbx.value = a[i]['idi'];
                    chckbx.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cbxval));
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```

I can get the values for 'cbxval' and it is seen in inspect element.. but I don't see the text in the html page that is created. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: You cannot add text to a checkbox. You need to create a seperate label.

Comment: You don't append the text node as a child. You put it along side. `document.getElementById("checkboxdiv").appendChild(document.createTextNode(cbxval));`

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: try to create `label` around `checkbox`,  it's simpler :) `lbl.appendChild(chckbx);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the textnode as child add it as a sibling.

```
chckbx.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("label"), chckbx.nextSibling);
```

JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/xzrsmbLL/